# How to change/update componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get that they deprecated componentWillReceiveProps and i am asked to replaced with getDerivedStateFromProps but they don't seem to do the same thing at all. Nor can getDerived... access this or setsetate. I looked at so many articles about converting to the new way and it doesn't apply to my case as i am not returning an object.

componentWillReceiveProps  is pushing this path "/dashboard" into this.props.history.

getDerivedStateFromProps HAS to return an object. How do i do this?

```
componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Login page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors,
      });
    }
  }
```

I tried doing the following but i get an error saying i have to return an object.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    return nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated
      ? nextProps.history.push("/dashboard")
      : { errors: nextProps.errors };
  }
```

**Edit: I tried ComponentDidUpdate by using the same method as the original code but that resulted in a crash.**

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (prevState.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: prevProps.errors,
      });
    }
  }
```

But this way it seems to work. No errors so far. But i'm not sure i understand why the code above fails.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(prevProps.auth, this.props.auth, this.props.history);
    if (prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated !== this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
    console.log(this.props.history);
    if (prevProps.errors !== this.props.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: this.props.errors,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't just use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function and check `this.props.auth.isAuthenticated` to issue side-effect of navigation?

Comment: I tried. I get this error "
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate."

Comment: Are you setting state unguarded within one of those functions? I.E. not checking against `prevProps`?

Comment: I edited my post with the code that failed. Also found something that works but i'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

In this example if there is any truthy error state then you continually set state which triggers another render cycle which updates state again... rinse & repeat until crash. This is what is called an unguarded state update.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
  }

  if (prevState.errors) {
    this.setState({
      errors: prevProps.errors, // <-- sets state and rerenders, repeatedly
    });
  }
}
```

## Solution

Use a guard check to compare the previous state and/or props to the current state and/or props, and only update state when the value has changed, once. This is why the second example doesn't create the state update cycle.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log(prevProps.auth, this.props.auth, this.props.history);
  if (prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated !== this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
  }

  console.log(this.props.history);
  if (prevProps.errors !== this.props.errors) { // <-- Only update error state if value different
    this.setState({
      errors: this.props.errors,
    });
  }
}
```

React docs [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> ```
> componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
>   // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
>   if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
>     this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You **may call `setState()` immediately** in `componentDidUpdate()` but note
> that **it must be wrapped in a condition** like in the example above, or
> you’ll cause an infinite loop.